# On the Choice Content of Carathéodory's Conformal Mapping Theorem

Tags: set-theory, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry, homological-algebra, axiom-of-choice

The [Schoenflies theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem), as a variant of the well-known [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem), states that the interior and the exterior planar regions determined by a simple closed curve (aka *Jordan curve*) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (through Jordan curve theorem) are homeomorphic to the interior and exterior of the unit disk respectively. Equivalently, any Jordan curve $\phi : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, can be extended to a homeomorphism $\psi : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ of the plane.

A closer look at the proof of this theorem suggests that it might be a little bit *choicy*. This is indeed the case, according to the following result of [Sakamoto and Yokoyama](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00153-007-0050-6):

> **Theorem (Sakamoto - Yokoyama).** Within $RCA_0$, Schönflies theorem is equivalent to [weak König’s lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_lemma) (which could be considered a very weak choice principle).

Here, a natural question arises:

> **Question 1.** Is any generalization or variant of Jordan-Schoenflies theorem equivalent to the full Axiom of Choice or makes an essential use of it? If yes, what is an example of a choiceless model of $ZF$ in which such a theorem fails?

Note that the failure of any such theorem (in the absence of choice) may result in the existence of very bizarre topological creatures of certain pathological behavior which could be of some interest as counterexamples. (As an analogy, see [Alexander's horned sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere) as a counterexample for the validity of Jordan–Schönflies theorem in three dimensions).

In order to narrow down the question 1, one may consider the case of the  [Carathéodory's conformal mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(conformal_mapping)) (which implies Schoenflies theorem) or [Alexander duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality):

> **Theorem (Carathéodory).** The conformal mapping sending the unit disk to the region in the complex plane bounded by a Jordan curve extends continuously to a homeomorphism from the unit circle onto the Jordan curve.

Now:

> **Question 2.** Does Carathéodory's conformal mapping theorem make an essential use of the Axiom of Choice? If yes, are they equivalent?

Comment: I don't have time to check this now (which is why this is a comment and not an answer), but it seems to me that one should be able to eliminate choice by an absoluteness argument. A Jordan curve, being a continuous map, can be coded by a single real $r$, and then one can work in the universe $L[r]$ of sets constructible from $r$, where choice holds. One needs to check that any real $s$ that codes an extension of your curve to a self-homeomorphism of the plane in $L[r]$ continues to do so in the whole universe. It seems that "codes a homeomorphism" and "extends" are absolute enough for this.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Sounds interesting! I will wait for a more expanded version of your argument as an answer! Thanks.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I will appreciate if you elaborate on this post by adding a detailed answer along the lines of the strategy that you have proposed in your comment. It seems there is still some degree of ambiguity in the argument which needs clarification. Thanks in advance! :-)